# When is Cech cohomology with compact support isomorphic to Singular cohomology with compact support?

Tags: cech-cohomology

This is a specific question regarding the understanding of a section of a paper. Having never posted here before I'm not sure that this is the right forum for this sort of question, but I hope someone can help.

Reading the paper by Wan https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82686957.pdf, I got stuck trying to understand why he requires Cech cohomology for Corollary 5.1. Here, he is considering a submanifold, possibly with boundary, of a smooth manifold without boundary. And for this submanifold he calculates Cech cohomology with compact support, when throughout the previous parts of the paper Singular cohomology had been used.
The submanifolds, called stable manifolds here, seem fairly nicely behaved, and my intuition was that Singular cohomology should coincide with Cech cohomology here.

Later, this is repeated in Lemma 6.2 as well.

Why is he forced to use Cech cohomology here? He refers to a theorem about relative cohomology, which requires Cech cohomology, but again, only if for the space in question the two cohomology theories differ.

Could it happen that for the stable manifolds Cech and Singular cohomology differ, with or without compact support?

Comment: The key point is mentioned in the proof of Lemma 6.2: that $\overline{H}^i_c(P\setminus R)=\overline{H}^i(P,R)$ for appropriate pairs $(P,R)$.  This is true in singular cohomology for pairs that are nice enough, but for Čech cohomology you need much less.  Also, there are various kinds of Poincaré-Lefschetz duality between homology and cohomology, and these need weaker assumptions if you use Čech cohomology.  There is an account starting on p.250 of https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT9580/v17/documents/adams-shgh.pdf, but I'm sure that there are other sources that are easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This is a useful reference. But I was wondering if there is a simpler explanation for why these cohomologies don't agree in this specific case. The stable manifolds, at first glance, seem to be very nice spaces, for which both cohomology theories should agree.